# Incorrect behavior with display: table and overflow: hidden in Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm going to use markup like this: http://jsfiddle.net/g6fo2grs/

So the main problem is in absolute positioned pseudo element 'before' contained in the second div. I'm using `overflow: hidden` to hide it if it's greater than container and I have problems with Firefox and IE because this style doesn't work with the `display: table` style. I should it use because second divs can contain different number of inner divs with different size and they should be stretched the width of the second div. That's why I use `display: table-cell` but it doesn't work without `display: table` for one third div. And I want to support IE8+ so I can't use flex. And finally I can't add new elements to this markup and I can't replace pseudo element by div.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Can't `clip` property solve your problem, since the "tables" have fixed size?

```
.second:before {
    /*
    all other styles unchanged
    */
    clip: rect(25px 552px 77px 50px);
}
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/g6fo2grs/4/

By the way, some of the features you use in the example (e.g. `rgba()` color and `border-radius`) are already incompatible with IE8.